# How do I get my app to display multiple user names?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Email and Password login from firebase auth.

Now when I change my account The displayed username will change depending on the changed account. I want to post multiple accounts without changing my username.

This is the code used to declare the name:

```
Widget displayUserInformation(context, snapshot) {
    final user = snapshot.data;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            user.displayName,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Sign Up Code:

```
// Email & Password Sign Up
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    final authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );
    // Update the username
    await updateUserName(name, authResult.user);
    return authResult.user.uid;
  }
```

Post code:

```
static Future<void> sendPostInFirebase(String postID, String postContent,
      MyProfileData displayName, String postImageURL) async {
    String postFCMToken;
    if (displayName.myFCMToken == null) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      postFCMToken = prefs.get('FCMToken');
    } else {
      postFCMToken = displayName.myFCMToken;
    }
    Firestore.instance.collection('thread').document(postID).setData({
      'postID': postID,
      'displayName': displayName.email,
      'userThumbnail': displayName.myThumbnail,
      'postTimeStamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      'postContent': postContent,
      'postImage': postImageURL,
      'postLikeCount': 0,
      'postCommentCount': 0,
      'FCMToken': postFCMToken
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I want to post multiple accounts'? you want to log into a new account and still have the previous account's username?

Comment: Save the usernames in firestore, then get it, display it and then send message to it.

Comment: I want to post my message on the app and it will show which account posted it. But now it shows all usernames as current accounts.

Comment: edit your question and add the function you use to post messages.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I have added an answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

On the message document, add a field called `username` that contains the username of who posted the message. Then display that username where you need it.

```
// ... other code here
Firestore.instance.collection('thread').document(postID).setData({
  'postID': postID,
  'displayName': displayName.email,
  'userThumbnail': displayName.myThumbnail,
  'postTimeStamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
  'postContent': postContent,
  'postImage': postImageURL,
  'postLikeCount': 0,
  'postCommentCount': 0,
  'FCMToken': postFCMToken,
  // add username of poster,
  'username': 'PUT THE USERNAME HERE',
  // e.g 'username': FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.displayName,
});
```

Then when you get the message, the username comes with it and you can access it like this: `message['username']` or `message.username` (if model is defined)